# Ошибка валидности

Tags: html

> **Line 43, Column 88**: Element img not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

`<img src="./assets/img/submenu_top.png" alt="" id="submenu_top"`**>**

> Contexts in which element img may be used: Where embedded content is
>   expected. Content model for element ul: Zero or more li elements.

При валидации кода, натолкнулся на несколько подобных ошибок. Красным показывает закрывающую скобку ">". Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOCTYPE XHTML? - тогда такая она должна быть: **`/>`**

Это во первых, а во вторых, судя по тексту вы в `<ul>` вкладываете `<img>`, что не положено. В `<ul>` положено вкладывать `<li>`, а в него уже картинки.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="./assets/img/submenu_top.png" alt="" id="submenu_top" />
    </li>
</ul>
```